# Drupal Multisite Creation using the same code base with multiple content databases

Tags: commerce, multi-sites

I am trying to create a multisite Drupal install which uses the same code base and a unique database for each site. I'm attempting to use the multisite wizard module to do this.

[image: screenshot]

After completing the above steps, when I select site 1 as 'From site' and site 2 as 'To site', the site 1 database is empty and its tables are inside the database for site 2. How can i have separate databases for my sites?

Comment: FYI: I've downvoted this because of the poor grammar, intentional spelling errors, and pseudo-language you've got going on. It's clear you've made no effort to ask a good quality question for our repository. Please treat this site with the respect that it deserves, and ask a proper, well-structured and formatted question.

Comment: sorry i modified it can you help in this now

Comment: Hello. I cleaned your question as much as I was able to. You can see the point where I gave up. I honestly don't understand what you are asking here. Bad language is despised on this site not because we are language purists. The main, maybe only reason is that bad language prevents good understanding. @Clive it seems OP tried. Do you understand him better than I do? If so, could you help? Because I reached limits of my abilities here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your using the drupal module [Multisite wizard](https://www.drupal.org/project/multisite_wizard)

This module doesn't seem to support one core multiple databases, only one core one database with multiple table prefixes. So all your data will be in the same Database in different prefixed tables.